# Google Extension Doesn't Append the HTML on Every Refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**My Manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Example Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This is an example extension.",
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "icons": {
      "16": "images/16.png",
      "48": "images/48.png",
      "64": "images/64.png",
      "128": "images/128.png"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
  },
"host_permissions":[ "https://www.example.com/api/post"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.example-target-url.com"],
      "js": ["assets/jquery-3.7.1.min.js","assets/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My Script File (content.js):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {

                var table = $('tbody > tr'); // target table

                $.each(table, function(key, value) {
                    var number = $(this).find('span.number__container')[0];
                    number = number.innerText;


                    var targetField = $(this).find('.target'); // last target class
                    var button = "<button id='createButton_" + key + "' value='" + number + "' class='btn btn-block secondary-button btn-mp-secondary'>+ Create</button>";
                    targetField.append(button).html();

                    $('#createButton_' + key).on('click', function() {

                        $('#createButton_' + key).prop('disabled', true).text('Creating...');

                        var settings = {
                            "url": "https://www.example.com/api/post",
                            "method": "POST",
                            "timeout": 0,
                            "data": {
                                "name": licenseId,
                                "number": number
                            }
                        };
                        $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (obj.code == 200) {
                                $('#createButton_' + key).addClass('btn btn-block secondary-button btn-mp-success').text('Success!');
                            } else {
                                $('#createButton_' + key).text('Not Created!');
                                window.alert(obj.content);
                            }
                        });
                    })
                })
        }, 2000);
});
```

The extension works properly when the buttons appears. My "Create" buttons are showing sometimes and working but It disappears when I refresh the page. When I try again, it still doesn't appear. For example, when I try for the third time, all buttons appears.

Extension not working stably. Can you help me on what should I do?

Thanks.

I tried;

- Timeout function
- runs_at: document_idle

Comment: Use MutationObserver to detect the parent element instead of $(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(

Comment: @Yogi No errors appear in the console. I don't know about mutationObServer. But I will search on Google. Thanks.